# Printing an index without running makeindex

Tags: luatex, makeindex

I have a complex program that makes an index seqB.idx and the corresponding seqB.ind.  I'd like to be able to use a much simpler LuaLaTeX program to process this and produce a PDF.  So I tried the following very minimal example, but it throws an error  `Package imakeidx Error: Misplaced \printindex[seqB].`

How to fix this?  Is there a way to generate the PDF from the command line?

```
\documentclass{article}%                                                                      

\RequirePackage{imakeidx}\makeindex%
\RequirePackage[unbalanced,indentunit=0.75em]{idxlayout}%

    \begin{document}                                                                

      \printindex[seqB]         

    \end{document}
```

with the existing seqB.ind e.g.

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item 2SA-3T: \hyperpage{35, 36}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K: \hyperpage{36}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3C: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3C; 3P: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3C; 3SA: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3C; 4T: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3C; 4K: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3C; 4C: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3C; 4P: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3P: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3P; 3SA: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3P; 4T: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3P; 4K: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3P; 4C: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3P; 4P: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3M: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-3SA: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-4m: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-4M: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3K-4SA: \hyperpage{39}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3C: \hyperpage{43}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3C-3P: \hyperpage{43}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3C-3P; 3SA: \hyperpage{43}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3C-3P; 4T: \hyperpage{43}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3C-3P; 4K: \hyperpage{43}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3C-3P; 4C: \hyperpage{43}
  \item 2SA-3T; 3C-3P; 4P: \hyperpage{43}

\end{theindex}
```